# Controller referencing data from tables not in direct relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been using the [Getting Started with EF using MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorials on ASP.net as a complete ASP.net and C# beginner, and have created a system which mimics the database highlight on the previous link, except this example is a hospital.

The table names are as follows, with relationships kept the same as the example.

```
Student = Patient
Enrollement = AdmissionDischargeTransfer (movement on patients in and out)
Course = Beds
Department = Wards
```

I have a Ward which shows all the beds in that ward, using the foreach as per the demo in the Ward View:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Wards)
</dt>
<dd>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Bed Number</th>
            <th>Patient Name</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Wards)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bed.BedTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        // How to display patient info?
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </table>
</dd>
```

Under AdmissionDischargeTransfer there is the PatientID, BedID, AdmissionDT, DischargeDT. I'm trying to select the patient currently admitted in that bed now based on current DT. Basically what I'm trying to do in words:

```
For each Bed with WardID 1
Select Patient Name from Patient Table where Admitted < Now and Discharged !=NULL
```

I presume the logic goes in the controller, however I'm struggling on what even to put in the controller. Can someone point me in the right direction of what to put or where to look?

Comment: Are you asking how to load data to pass to the page?

Comment: I presume so. It's being able to reference the correct patient in relation to the bed they are in.

Comment: Assuming you have your relationships correctly configured and navigation properties exist you should be able to do something like context.Wards.Include(w => w.Beds.Select(b => b.Patient)) then you can do Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bed.Patient.PatientName)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.